# How to evalutate $ \int_{\Bbb V}{\arctan(x y^2 z^3)} \, dx \, dy \, dz $ where $ \Bbb V = \{ x^2 + y^2 \le 1, \, 0 \le z \le x^2 \} $?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Consider: $ \Bbb V = \{ x^2 + y^2 \le 1, \, 0 \le z \le x^2 \} $, then evalutate the integral:
$$ \int_{\Bbb V}{\arctan(x y^2 z^3)} \, dx \, dy \, dz $$

---

My attempt:

1. The function is such that $f(x,y,z)=-f(-x, y,z)$;
2. The domain is such that $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb V \Rightarrow (-x,y,z) \in \Bbb V$;
   -since $(x)$ appears only squared: even the interval of $(z)$ doesn't distinguish $(x)$ from $(-x)$

Thus, the integral is null by symmetry.

---

I tried to compute this integral with Wolfram Cloud to check the result, by this code:
`\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= x^2, {x, y, z}]; Integrate[ArcTan[x y^2 z^3], {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]]`

But I got: "This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan"

---

Can anyone confirm (or refute) my attempt?

Comment: What you have is correct. Good job!

Comment: @DOmonoXYLEDyL If you want Wolfram to give a quick answer you can just use: NIntegrate[
 ArcTan[x*y^2*z^3], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
  Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, {z, 0, x^2}]